# best way to allow users to modify a toolbar of links (change order, add, remove)

Tags: php, html, css

I've seen several sites that allow users to arrange toolbars (changing the order of links and adding or removing).

What's the best way to do this?

I'd probably do the following:

Create a new numeric db field 'listorder' on users table where the order of links is saved in.

Each link represents a number. Something like this would be in a new table for the links:
first link - 1
second link - 2
third link - 3 etc

Default 'listorder' would look like: 123
Custom user arranged: 231

To display the html:
Take 231 apart to an array and find the appropriate content for each link from the db (the new links table).

This looks like it would slow the site down quite due to the queries.

**Does anyone know a better way to do something like this?**

Cookies wouldn't work. The order has to be permanent and saved on the user's account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you wanted the value to persist throughout cookie clearage..**

store the ID in a serialized cell in a table. use ajax to save the data onchange of the ul elements. use JqueryUI to implement drag n drop of toolbar items. use php to serialize and save the order as submitted back into the table.

**update:** I wouldn't use serialized specifically, simple semi-colon delimited would suffice..

`IE: $link_order = '1;3;2;6;10;13';`

Use PHP `<?php explode(';',$link_order); ?>`

**If you just need it as a "temporary" thing..** 
use cookies and jquery onchange. same method as above just dont use php/db

if you need sample code of both, let me know.

Comment: option #1: server/client side, a bit more work.. but does not rely on the set of cookies. Option #2: relies on cookies, but takes processing time/load off of your server and puts it on the backs of the users.. Make sure to throw this code at the footer of the document.

Comment: also to note, you could use memcached, or another form of memory caching to lighten the loafers of the server a bit. Or even store both, cookie and db... do a quick timestamp check between a cookie value and a db value.. if the timestamps don't match, resave a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much better to have a set default order in your HTML/CSS.

Then, for customization you'd use javascript to check for a cookie on the client's machine and dynamically rearrange the order based on stylesheet or ordering preferences stored there. IMHO, this isn't something it makes sense to add database overhead to accomplish. PHP isn't necessarily the right tool for the job.

Comment: Without editing my answer, I'd add that it if you have a large number of user configuration settings and you're already storing those in the database, it would make sense to go ahead and add one more. However, as a one-off solution I'd keep the display logic where it generally belongs: in the HTML and CSS

Answer (score -1):

you need to assign a field "orderField" in your user's db. so each one can alter their own way. if you want to avoid having 9000 fields per users. i recommand putting id's separated tags (1-2-6-4-3) and then you take the one that aren't listed to set them after (in case you add some other fields later on.

Comment: It is best practice to not use dashes or slashes, that eliminates the possibility for negative integers and could cause problems. It is best to use commas or semicolons..

Comment: true, good point, but since he use only positive integers, it shouldn't matter (negative field id???)